# discord-buttons throws an error for no reason

Tags: javascript, discord.js, discord-buttons

My program keeps throwing this error for no reason:

[image]

The error happened in those lines:

```js
const client = new discord.Client({ intents: ['GUILDS', 'GUILD_MESSAGES','GUILD_MEMBERS'], partials: ['GUILD_MEMBER']});
const disbut = require('discord-buttons');
disbut(client);
```

I use discord.js v13.1.0 by the way, Any help?

Comment: I think you have a typo somewhere in your code. Do you have another class called `sendAPICallback`? if so replace `dAPIMessage` with `APIMessage`.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code before these lines (i.e. every import)?

Comment: @halilcakar the error is coming from the [`discord-buttons`](https://github.com/discord-buttons/discord-buttons/blob/2dd931fca786b54f26f470d5179a197d0181e77b/src/v12/Classes/APIMessage.js#L9) package.

Comment: I would recommend you not to use the `discord-buttons` package, since discord.js v13 has native support for Buttons. The package looks deprecated and only for discord.js v12.